# $R(A) v$ notation in homomorphism from $SU(2)$ to $SO(3)$

Tags: notation, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to follow a great [course on Lie theory](https://youtu.be/Zmotyd_xn7g) online, and I am a bit confused by the overloading of notation when it gets to this point:

> If $A \in SU(2),$ then $AM_vA^{-1} \in {\frak {su}}(2)\;\; \forall\; M_v\in \frak {su}(2),$ wich implies that $AM_vA^{-1}=M_w$ for some $w\in \mathbb R^3.$
>
> Moreover, $w=R(A)v$ for some rotation $R(A),$ such that $AM_vA^{-1}=M_{R(A)v.}$

I tend to think that what's going on here is that the Lie algebra for $SU(2)$ can be represented as

$$M_v=\begin{bmatrix} ix & y+iz \\ -y + iz & -ix \end{bmatrix}$$

or equivalently by the vector $v=\begin{bmatrix}x & y & z \end{bmatrix}^\top.$

Conjugating  $M_v$ with $A$ will land us back in the Lie algebra with a new matrix $M_w,$ or equivalently, a new vector $w=\begin{bmatrix}\tilde x & \tilde y & \tilde z \end{bmatrix}^\top.$

These two vectors $v$ and $w$  will have the same magnitude, and correspond to a rotation around the origin. The "generator" of this new matrix is $A,$ but what are exactly $R(A)$ and $R(A)v$?

My intuition is that it is possibly a simple notational trick to express that $R(A)$ applied to $v$ is the rotation on $v$ that ends up producing $w$ via the conjugation $AM_v A^{-1}.$ So would be not a function $R(\cdot)$ of $A,$ but rather a rotation of $v$ that is obtained in such way.

In fact I'm pretty sure now - and will leave it in the OP as opposed to an answer to invite a more formal post - that $R(A)$ is a linear transformation (i.e. a matrix) acting on a vector $v$ and yielding a vector $w.$ Therefore $R(A)v=w.$ And $M_{R(A)v} = AM_vA^{-1}=M_w.$

This transformation is orthogonal (preserving inner product), and hence,

$$R: SU(2) \to O(3)$$

> Or does $R(\cdot)$ stand for "representation"?

Comment: You *can* illustrate all these statements trivially with [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector), right?